# Есть ли достойное применение isUserAGoat()?

Tags: java, android

Что нужно сделать, чтобы вернулось `true/false`?

Comment: Дать телефон какому-нибудь козлу[?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13375357/276994)

Comment: это где такое?))

Comment: [metalurgus][1], этот вопрос надо адресовать [OHA][2] )))



  [2]: http://www.openhandsetalliance.com/
  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/3997/metalurgus

Answer (score 5):

Начиная с API 21, данный метод проверяет, установлено ли у пользователя на устройстве приложение `com.coffeestainstudios.goatsimulator`:

```
/**
 * Used to determine whether the user making this call is subject to
 * teleportations.
 *
 * <p>As of {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#LOLLIPOP}, this method can
 * now automatically identify goats using advanced goat recognition technology.
 * </p>
 *
 * @return Returns true if the user making this call is a goat.
 */
public boolean isUserAGoat() {
    return mContext.getPackageManager()
            .isPackageAvailable("com.coffeestainstudios.goatsimulator");
}
```

**[Исходный код](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.0_r6/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java#442)**

В ранних версиях (до API 21) этот метод всегда возвращал `false`, так как на тот момент, вероятно, ещё не существовало хорошей реализации системы распознавания козлов.

**UPDATE:**

Начиная c API 30 (Android 11), метод [всегда](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/1f6e0b89b2ca870525132385e46d2bd8eb1d1ef0:core/java/android/os/UserManager.java;dlc=b0d967095377ed4b774efebf3de199a1037c9317) возвращает `false`, чтобы обеспечить достаточный уровень приватности для наших братьев меньших.

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * Used to determine whether the user making this call is subject to
 * teleportations.
 * @return whether the user making this call is a goat
 */
public boolean isUserAGoat() {
    return false;
}
```

Он никогда не вернет true))

Comment: Хм. А есть ли у класса декларация `sealed`?

Comment: @VladD, Можно еще попробовать #define false true, если в Java таковой имеется.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша: нету. Кроме того, у Java отсутствуют заголовочные файлы.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. Буду знать)

Comment: Ну это я ещё не спрашивал про isUserAMonkey() :)
Вот он возвращает истину при нескольких обстоятельствах.

Comment: > Он никогда не вернет true))

Утверждение не верно. Такое описание метода подразумевает его НЕ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНУЮ реализацию (в данном случае производителем аппарата).
Иными словами, вполне возможно, что телефон уважающего себя производителя запросто определит превращение юзера в козла при телепортации)))

Comment: Начиная с API 21, метод isUserAGoat() идентифицирует козлов, используя новейшую систему распознавания козлов. Исходник https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.0_r6/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java

Answer (score 3):

> Что нужно сделать, чтобы вернулось `true`

Установить игру [Goat Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coffeestainstudios.goatsimulator) на устройстве с Android 5.0+
На более ранних версиях Android эта функция всегда возвращала `false`